# How to convert raster DEM to reduce file size in QGIS? e.g. 32 to 8 bit floating point

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, convert, floating-point

I have a raster DTM (.tif, 32 bit floating point) which has a very large file size and is thus slowing down the software. I am looking for a way of reducing the file size without reducing grid cell size (50cm).

I tried SAGA>Raster tools>Convert data storage type
However, it gives me an error: ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details]

I also got the same error with Terrain Analysis - Hydrology>Catchment Area

I'm not so familiar with manually editing the text/code in processing tool, so please forgive me if there's a quick solution there I've overlooked.

**Here's the log results:**

```
Algorithm Convert data storage type starting...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\ca82edbf27224883aa8b815fecc65474\DTM50cmMERGE01.sgrd" -FILES "G:/Project Centre/Anybody/MGreen/GIS/Local/Ferry Lane/LIDAR-DTM-50CM/Modified/DTM-50cm-MERGE-01.tif"
grid_tools "Convert Data Storage Type" -INPUT "C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\ca82edbf27224883aa8b815fecc65474\DTM50cmMERGE01.sgrd" -TYPE 8 -OUTPUT "C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\9598a863de744b41996a45713612037d\OUTPUT.sdat"

C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga

C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin>PATH=c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga;C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\ca82edbf27224883aa8b815fecc65474\DTM50cmMERGE01.sgrd" -FILES "G:/Project Centre/Anybody/MGreen/GIS/Local/Ferry Lane/LIDAR-DTM-50CM/Modified/DTM-50cm-MERGE-01.tif"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.


ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.



C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin>saga_cmd grid_tools "Convert Data Storage Type" -INPUT "C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\ca82edbf27224883aa8b815fecc65474\DTM50cmMERGE01.sgrd" -TYPE 8 -OUTPUT "C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\9598a863de744b41996a45713612037d\OUTPUT.sdat"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.


ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.


_____________________________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
_____________________________________________

_____________________________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\saga\modules\grid_tools.dll
library name: Grid - Tools
tool name : Convert Data Storage Type
author : O.Conrad (c) 2003
_____________________________________________

Load grid: C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\ca82edbf27224883aa8b815fecc65474\DTM50cmMERGE01.sgrd...
failed

Usage: saga_cmd grid_tools 11 -INPUT [-OUTPUT ] [-TYPE ]
-INPUT: Grid
Grid (input)
-OUTPUT: Converted Grid
Grid (optional output)
-TYPE: Data storage type
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] bit
[1] unsigned 1 byte integer
[2] signed 1 byte integer
[3] unsigned 2 byte integer
[4] signed 2 byte integer
[5] unsigned 4 byte integer
[6] signed 4 byte integer
[7] 4 byte floating point number
[8] 8 byte floating point number
Default: 0
Error: Grid file could not be opened.
Error: input file [C:\Users\MGreen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing78d8a68235ae48bdb275523d7015c81f\ca82edbf27224883aa8b815fecc65474\DTM50cmMERGE01.sgrd]
Error: Grid
Error: executing tool [Convert Data Storage Type]

C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin>exit
Converting outputs

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details
```

Comment: Can you add the information found in the log to your question (see http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/log.html if you need help finding this)?